# Unity Shader Graph: How to speed up time from Time node?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm trying to use Sine Time output from Time node but I want it to be faster.

If this is done in a Unity c#, I would try to something like this

```
totalTime += Time.deltaTime * speed;

value = Mathf.PingPong(totalTime, 1);
```

but I can't do this in Shader Graph. How to solve this problem?

EDIT1: I also try to create custom node fuction but this will result in error.

```
static string PingPongFunction(
    [Slot(0, Binding.None)] Vector1 t,
    [Slot(1, Binding.None)] Vector1 length,
    [Slot(2, Binding.None)] out Vector1 Out)
{
    return
        @"
            {
                Out = Mathf.PingPong(t, length);
            }
        ";
}
```

Comment: I've not got much experience with shader graphs but I think the multiply node should work. pass your time into a on the multiply node and then you can either manually set B to say 2 to go twice as fast or add a new vector1 property so you can change it from the inspector.

Answer (score 7):

Feed time as x to sin(x) and multiply time with a number to speed it up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this pass your time into `A` on the `multiply node` and then you can either manually set `B` to 2 to go twice as fast or add a new vector1 property so you can change it from the inspector.

[image: Shader Graph Example]

Comment: is it possible to clamped value to desire range like [0, 1], just like Mathf.PingPong( does?

Comment: You can use a remap node with a 0 to 1 output

Comment: @FaxFrag Use a `Math -> Sine` node.